# PHPSpreadsheet works in XAMPP but not Apache on Raspbian

Tags: php, raspbian, phpspreadsheet

I setup a small reporting tool with phpSpreadsheet that basically takes some data from one .xlsx and puts it in another .xlsx. It worked like a charm with XAMPP but now that I set it up on a raspberry-pie with raspbian and an apache-Server it just doesn't get the data from the file anymore it seems.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;

$readsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("campaignList.xlsx");
$datasheet = $readsheet->getActiveSheet();
echo $datasheet->getCell('C1')

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($readsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('campaignList2.xlsx');
```

Sadly it doesn't echo anything, nor does it generate the new file, nor does it give any error-messages. I installed composer and phpspreadhseet the same way I did for XAMPP with composer (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and for the apache setup I followed this guide: https://hackedit.de/530/. Sadly I wasn't able to catch any errors there so I'am kinda confused how to move on from here.

I would be very grateful for any tips you lovely people could proivde regarding this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all needed Apache Modules?

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest

- PHP extension php_zip enabled
- PHP extension php_xml enabled
- PHP extension php_gd2 enabled (if not compiled in)

And turned the Apache log on?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: I think they should be enabled.

root@raspberrypi:~# php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

By excluding the writer,I managed to get one step futher and at least read a cell. But the moment I try to modify the sheet (remove a row) nothing works.

Comment: See you an error message while writing the excel or see you nothing?

Comment: Sadly I see nothing, which is the odd thing about it. I don't even where I should stark looking for the error.

Comment: So to narrow it down. It does read files, but it doesn't write files. So the writer part of the code, just doesn't work allthough I can read from the file.